# How can I create a language toggle for a wordpress website that actually changes the menu options language as well?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, toggle

I have an wordpress website which I have to translate to english and spanish. I have created a toggle button to change the content language by setting each language link to a page with different content (i know that is probably dumb) but I just cannot change the language of the sidebars, header and footer. How do I solve this? What can I do so I just have my whole page translated when clicking the button?

Unfortunately I just cannot use any plug-ins, I have to do it completely manually.

Comment: why did you post this question if you don't watch the answers?

Answer (score 0):

to directly change page link  to english and spanish mains pages use `<base>` tag ( see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base )

for texts just add / remove a `noDisplay` class as appropriate

to keep Language selection for Every page and next connection use **LocalStorage** -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

sample code (I use  it in a closure Object)
*this is just a start code, you have to complete it for your own app*

```js
const LangChooser = (function()
{
  const cLangElm  = document.querySelectorAll('.cLang')
    ,   langList  = ['EN', 'SP']  // english  or spanish pages pages 
    ,   defLang   = 'EN'
    ,   obj_ret   = {}
    ,   MemoLang  = 'LangChoosed'  // name value in local storage
    ;
  let idxLang = langList.indexOf(defLang) 
    ;
  function LangdSet(lang)
    {
    localStorage.setItem(MemoLang, lang )
      ;      
    cLangElm.forEach(Elm=>
      {
      if (Elm.classList.contains(lang)) 
        { Elm.classList.remove('noDisplay')}
      else 
        { Elm.classList.add('noDisplay')}
      })
    }
  obj_ret.LangInit = function()
    {
    let currentLang = localStorage.getItem(MemoLang)
      ;
    if (!currentLang)
      {
      currentLang = defLang
      }
    idxLang = langList.indexOf(currentLang) 
    LangdSet(currentLang) 
    }
  obj_ret.setLang = function(lang) 
    {
    let idx = langList.indexOf(lang)
    if (idx<0)
      {
      throw `${lang} language doesn't exist here !`;
      }
    idxLang = idx;
    LangdSet(lang)
    }
  obj_ret.toogleNextLang = function()
    {
    idxLang = ++idxLang %2
    LangdSet(langList[idxLang] )
    }
  obj_ret.getLang = function()
    {
    return langList[idxLang]
    }
  return obj_ret
})()
  ;
function configurePageLang()
  {
  let currentLang = LangChooser.getLang()

  // change bage..
  direction.textContent =' base = ' + currentLang
  pageLink.href = currentLang + '/'
  }

//on load...
LangChooser.LangInit()
configurePageLang()

btLang.onclick=()=>
  {
  LangChooser.toogleNextLang()
  configurePageLang()
  }
```

```css
.noDisplay { display:none }
```

```html
<base id="pageLink" href="EN/">

<p id="direction"> base = EN </p>

<button id="btLang"> page EN / SP </button>

<p>
  <a href="Page2.html"> a link to page 2</a>
  <!--  go to EN/Page2.html  or SP/Page2.html   -->
</p>

<p class="cLang EN"> This is text in English </p>
<p class="cLang SP noDisplay"> Este es texto en español </p>
```